# Norm and Determinant relation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ whose colums are the vectors $v_1,v_2$, it is known that
$$
|\det(A)|=\|v_1\|\cdot \|v_2\|\cdot \sin \measuredangle (v_1,v_2)
$$

with usual euclidean norm. I think there is a generalization of this formula for $k$ vectors (which still expresses the determinant in terms of norms and sines), so my question is if someone knows it.

Comment: Yes, for $k$ vectors the determinant measures the volume of the parallelepiped whose edges are the vectors. I don't know a formula off-hand for this volume in terms of the angles, but in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for instance you get the scalar triple product.

Comment: look under [solid angle of tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) for a similar formula by Oosterom and Strackeey

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know a little about these facts, but i really need a formula with this aspect for higher dimensions.